# Why does .ico ( Base64 ) appear to waste so much space?

Tags: javascript, base64, gimp

Below is the base64 representation of my logo icon.  It is mostly the character A.  I made it in gimp and then converted it to base64.

Is there something I could have done differently so that I do not waste so much space.  I would assume there is someway to encode A over and over again, instead of explicitly writing them?

I know that Base64 kills 33% off the top, but this is not my concern.

In gimp I save to .ico and then converted to Base64 using an [online tool.](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)

> url(data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,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

.../snip continues like this

Comment: I assume that your icon is a BMP-encoded and not PNG-encoded. Chances are, Base64 has nothing to do with this, and your icon just has that much repetition. Raw bitmaps often do. Can you verify this with a hex editor?

Comment: What options does the Gimp provide? Can you encode as PNG?

Comment: A is `000000`, not `1010`.

Comment: Because Base64 is not a compression algorithm. If it meets same data again and again, it will produce same results without looking back what there already was. And its output by design will take more space than input. If you need to save or transfer any data (non printable byte values, null bytes etc.) where only simple text can go, Base64 is your tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows icon files contain raw uncompressed bitmap data, and Base64 is just a way of encoding data with a 33% expansion rate.

Depending on what you're wanting to do, there are several solutions:

- Use the PNG ICO format: this is a normal multi-image'd Windows *.ico file, except the bitmap data is stored as PNG instead of a raw bitmap. This is only supported by Windows Vista or later. (PNGs are used for 128x128 and larger icon sizes but bitmaps are used for all smaller sizes for compatibility and performance reasons).
- Use PNG directly - it doesn't look like you're taking advantage of the multi-image capabilities of the ICO format, is this for a favicon? Note that favicons can be in any bitmap format, not just ICO.
- Use your webserver's GZIP compression - assuming you're offering your ICO files over the web then the inefficient storage isn't a concern because most servers, including IIS, come with HTTP Gzip compression support which really shrinks those things down.

Other than that, I/we need more information about what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Save it as a 16x16 PNG image directly, then define `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="myIcon.png" />` in your website's pages.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as a 2 color palette GIF file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the Base64 value, you could write a loop to make that many As I suppose. Depending on the length of the loop it may or may not save file space.

Comment: I guess it just depends on often you're going to need to be doing stuff like this.  I wouldn't write my own function just to save a few K, but if a lot more was at stake it might be worth it.